What is the quickest way to group and analyze large data (~150MM+ rows)?
I have a large dataset of historical power prices (151mm+). There are 18,065 individual nodes where prices settle, each with hourly observations (8760/yr).
Data schema: Node ID (int64), Datetime (datetime), and Price (float64). Node IDs are int64, 7 digit long keys. Datetime are datetime. Price are float64.
For each node, I need annual average volatility as follows:

avg(highest 4 hrs) - avg(lowest 4 hrs) for all days
average of all daily spreads to get one data point per node per year

I have tried various methods of pd.groupby and nsmallest/nlargest. I tried grouping the whole dataframe, then chunking the data, and subsetting with  each unique Node ID. The best I've been able to do is with the below code which averages about 2 Node IDs/second, totaling about 2.5 hours.
dd = pd.read_csv(".\ERCOT LMP 2023.csv")
n = 2
dd['Local Datetime (Hour Ending)'] = pd.to_datetime(dd['Local Datetime (Hour Ending)'], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
node_ix = dd['Price Node ID'].unique()
dd.drop('Price Node Name', axis = 1, inplace = True)
def tb4(df, n):
    grp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Local Datetime (Hour Ending)', freq = 'D'))
    high = grp['Price $/MWh'].nlargest(n).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis = 1).groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Local Datetime (Hour Ending)', freq = 'D'))['Price $/MWh'].mean()
    low = grp['Price $/MWh'].nsmallest(n).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis = 1).groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Local Datetime (Hour Ending)', freq = 'D'))['Price $/MWh'].mean()
    return high - low    

results = []
time_start = dt.datetime.now()
time_log = []

for i in range(len(node_ix)):
    loop_start = dt.datetime.now()
    tmp = dd[dd['Price Node ID'] == node_ix[i]].copy()
    tmp.drop('Price Node ID', axis = 1, inplace = True)
    results += [(node_ix[i], tb4(tmp, n).mean())]
    loop_end = dt.datetime.now()
    time_log += [loop_end-loop_start]
    avg_time = sum(time_log,dt.timedelta()) / len(time_log)
    print(f"{dt.datetime.now().strftime(format = '%H:%M:%S')} -- {i+1}/{len(node_ix)} -- Estimated finish: {(avg_time * (len(node_ix) - i)  + time_start).strftime(format = '%H:%M:%S')}")

Best attempt at MRE as advised below, goal is to obtain diff for large amounts of individual IDs assuming they all have a year's worth of hourly data.
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq = 'H'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime' : dates,
                  'id': 1,
                  'price': np.random.uniform(-20.00, 200.00, size = (len(dates)))})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime' : dates,
                  'id': 2,
                  'price': np.random.uniform(-20.00, 200.00, size = (len(dates)))})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0)

top = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'D')])['price'].nlargest(2).reset_index().drop('level_2', axis = 1).groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'D')])['price'].mean()
bottom = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'D')])['price'].nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop('level_2', axis = 1).groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'D')])['price'].mean()
diff = (top - bottom).reset_index().groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'Y')]).mean()

Here is a data sample:
Data Sample
I am iterating over a unique list of nodes.

could you give a sample of the data that you are processing?

It looks like you are iterating over the entire data set, getting some data based on the group of price node ids (using vola) and then storing that as a result, however it seems that depending on how many price node ids that you have you are doing the same calculation over and over for each group as you iterate through your dataframe. It would probably be best to get the unique price node ids and only iterate through that list to get the results that you want.

Additionally, you should probably access the items directly instead of trying to iterate over a range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-can-i-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Thanks Andrew, I just updated the question to reflect your comments. I am iterating over a list of unique nodes. Data sample provides a few hours for one unique node.

There's a lot to go through here. Please try to narrow the problem down into a [mre]. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples (e.g. for performance questions, you can use seeded random values). Details should be provided as text, not a picture. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for more tips.

FWIW, instead of list += [item], use list.append(item). It should be a bit faster, but it doesn't seem like the main problem here.

Can we get more data in text format? I would probably look at this as a map/reduce problem and process the data one row at a time and accumulate the observed 4 best and worst prices.

Thank you all for the comments - I made some edits to hopefully make this clearer and added an MRE.

Is the data available here https://www.ercot.com/mktinfo/rtm ? so that we can test it locally to provide some assistance

@AndrewRyan - you could to to link and download RTMLZHBSPP_2023 for complete 2023 data. Data are by 15min (delivery interval). Either agg up or just pick one interval per hour. Settlement point names are individual nodes in my example.

So this may provide some speed-ups in eliminating some unnecessary function calls and trying to streamline data accessing:
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def tb4(df: pd.DataFrame, n: int) -> pd.Series: # added types just to make it more readable of what you are dealing with
    grp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Local Datetime (Hour Ending)', freq = 'D'))['Price $/MWh'] # added selector at end because both high + low used so store value once and reuse
    high = grp.nlargest(n).reset_index()['Price $/MWh'].mean() # removed .drop('level_1', axis = 1).groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Local Datetime (Hour Ending)', freq = 'D')) because all it seems to do is drop a part of the table (which doesn't matter as you are only looking at a portion of it anyways and not reusing it elsewhere), and then having another groupby which does the same thing as the first grouping having no real impact and just extra run time
    low = grp.nsmallest(n).reset_index()['Price $/MWh'].mean() # same as for high
    return high - low


dd = pd.read_csv("/Users/vortex/Downloads/ERCOT LMP 2023.csv")
dd['Local Datetime (Hour Ending)'] = pd.to_datetime(dd['Local Datetime (Hour Ending)'], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
node_ix = dd['Price Node ID'].unique()
#dd.drop('Price Node Name', axis = 1, inplace = True)

results = []
time_start = dt.datetime.now()
time_log = []
n = 2

for node in node_ix: # updated to node so that you access the values directly instead of trying to index into the value (faster generally and preferred)
    loop_start = dt.datetime.now()
    tmp = dd[dd['Price Node ID'] == node].copy()
    tmp.drop('Price Node ID', axis = 1, inplace = True)
    results.append((node, tb4(tmp, n))) # removed .mean() because already getting a value from func tb4 - just need to access it # removed += to append because += is a slower method than append (for lists)
    loop_end = dt.datetime.now()
    time_log.append(loop_end-loop_start) # removed += to append because += is a slower method than append (for lists)
    avg_time = sum(time_log,dt.timedelta()) / len(time_log)
    print(f"{dt.datetime.now().strftime(format = '%H:%M:%S')} -- {i+1}/{len(node_ix)} -- Estimated finish: {(avg_time * (len(node_ix) - i)  + time_start).strftime(format = '%H:%M:%S')}")

Note I did not test it with the full sample data (as it was not already in the format that you are using)
If further improvements are required, I would recommend sampling your code to see what areas require the most attention to improve timing.
